# How can we cover code in test class under Site.createPortalUser?

Tags: apex, force.com-sites

Our class code looks like this:

```
    String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);
    if (userId != null) { 
        if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
            return Site.login(username, password, null);
        }
        else {
            PageReference page = System.Page.SiteRegisterConfirm;
            page.setRedirect(true);
            return page;
        }
    }
```

Site.createPortalUser always returns false while running test class.
How can we cover code under if(userId != null) ?

Comment: You have to use Test.isRunningTest();

Comment: You don't have to. It's just one way. One I would avoid wherever possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could certainly use mocking here. Create a `virtual` service class to call that method, and then your test classes can override the implementation.

```
public virtual with sharing class SiteService
{
    public static Id createPortalUser(SObject user, String accountId, String password)
    {
        return service.shadowCreatePortalUser(user, accountId, password);
    }

    static SiteService service = new SiteService();
    @TestVisible static void setMock(SiteService mock) { service = mock; }

    @TestVisible virtual Id shadowCreatePortalUser(SObject user, String accountId, String password)
    {
        return Site.createPortalUser(user, accountId, password);
    }
}
```

Then use this injection-friendly service instead in your implementation:

```
public with sharing class MyClass
{
    public static void doStuff(/*parameters*/)
    {
        Id userId = SiteService.createPortalUser(user, accountId, password);
        // further processing
    }
}
```

Then, in your test, you can set a mock so you can test the non-null execution path.

```
@IsTest
class MyClassTests
{
    class MockSiteService extends SiteService
    {
        public override Id shadowCreatePortalUser(SObject user, String accountId, String password)
        {
            return UserInfo.getUserId();
        }
    }

    @IsTest static void testDoStuff_NonNullUserId()
    {
        // data setup

        Test.startTest();
            SiteService.setMock(new MockSiteService());
            MyClass.doStuff(/*parameters*/);
        Test.stopTest();

        // meaningful assertions
    }
}
```